# stick a image to the bottom right corner

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How can i stick a image to the bottom right corner of the screen?

```
local screenGroup = self.view
helpbtn = display.newImage("helpbtn.png")
screenGroup:insert(helpbtn)
helpbtn.x = 255; helpbtn.y = 600
transition.to( helpbtn, { time=2500, y=465, transition=easing.inOutExpo } )
```

So on all the different devices it will look the same ?

Comment: do you mean positioned at same place, or also occupy same fraction of screen?

Comment: i mean always in the corner regarding the screen size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
local distanceFromCorner = 5
local helpbtn = display.newImage("helpbtn.png")
screenGroup:insert(helpbtn)
helpbtn.x = display.contentWidth  - helpbtn.contentWidth/2 - distanceFromCorner;
helpbtn.y = display.contentHeight - helpbtn.contentHeight/2 - distanceFromCorner;
```

You can also make use of [object:setReferencePoint(display.BottomRightReferencePoint)](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/setReferencePoint.html) in normal corona modes or [Anchor Points](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/10/15/tutorial-anchor-points-in-graphics-2-0/) in Corona’s Graphics 2.0 engine.

Keep Coding.................. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use display.contentWidth and display.contentHeight. Also look at other SO posts like [Corona SDK Cross Device Screen Resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769319/corona-sdk-cross-device-screen-resolution) and on google for "corona lua screen (size OR resolution)".